# How can I ignore all children classes in CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, formio

I am using formio to fast generate form in my website. Then I want to put a MUI component inside of form generated by formio. I can put it in but the component applied a formio css style. How can I prevent it?

```
<div class="formio-component">
  <div class="formio-form">
    <!-- Some content -->

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12>

        <div class="mui-component">
          <!-- MUI component that I want to ignore -->
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- More content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

It is my bootstrap css file:

```
.formio-component {
  // Bootstrap css
}
```

I modified the bootstrap css file but not working

```
.formio-component :not(.mui-component) {
  // Bootstrap css
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.